# Is there a way to execute git-grep command on a remote repository tree?

Tags: git, grep, repository, git-grep

I would like to search the contents of files located in one of subtrees of the remote repository (origin/master).
`git-grep` documentation says that command works on a current working tree. Consequently, how can I search through files that make up remote repo tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in git. Either you fetch the remote commits locally or use out-of-git access to the remote repository. With ssh you just do `ssh remote-host "cd /repo && git grep"`. With web access use whatever search is provided.